# RxJS5 -- need help figuring out the right flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

Here's the code:

```js
const oids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

// func to get mongodb cursor
const getCursor = oid => mdb.content.collection.find({
  status: {
    $in: [1, 2]
  },
  oid
}, {
  _id: -1,
  oid: 1,
  description: 1,
});

// scan func to accumulate text
const accumulateText = (acc = '', post) => acc += ' ' + post.description;

// generating innerObservables
const getInnerObservable$ = oid => {
  // first, set the MongoDB cursor
  const cursor = getCursor(oid);

  return Rx.Observable
    // create an observable from cursor's data event
    .fromEvent(cursor, 'data')
    // and read until there's no more data
    .takeUntil(
      Rx.Observable.fromEvent(cursor, 'end')
    )
    // accumulate text from every document that fits the condition
    .reduce(accumulateText)
    // AFTER EVERY DOCUMENT HAD BEEN THROUGH THE SCAN
    // map the accumulated text through a word frequency count function
    .map(str => helpers.countWordFrequency(str))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
};

const content$ = Rx.Observable
  .from(oids)
  // for each oid, get an inner observable
  .mergeMap(getInnerObservable$);


return new Promise((res, rej) => content$.subscribe({
    next: (v) => console.log(v),
    complete: () => res()
  }))
  .then(() => console.log('Done'));
```

Basically, I know that my approach is wrong, but I'm utterly confused as to how to implement it the right way. I've added some comments in the code to help understand what I am going for.

I am using RxJS5 and Node 7.1.0.

Appreciate any help and/or feedback.

EDIT: I found out that there's a `reduce` method (edited the code), which seems to do the job but then eventually the documents just start to bypass it entirely for some reason. I have no idea why this is happening. Seems like there's some fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

EDIT2: Essentially, for some reason, some of the data simply skips the reduce method on the observer returned by the `getInnerObservable$` and somehow directly skips to the `map` method. I still have no idea why, but other than that, it works as intended. Any ideas? I'm at a complete loss, honestly.

Comment: I have some good experience with RxJS5, but I'm no expert. That said, in all of my time, I've never seen a subscription nested inside of a promise.  What advantage is there to that nesting?  Also, my experience to Mongo is limited, but I don't think that the database emits values over time.  That's RxJS's desired use case.  If `cursor` returns synchronous data, using RxJS is needlessly complicating things.  RxJS is great for something like RethinkDB's change feeds.

Comment: @D.Walsh The nesting is just so I could return a promise from the function after the chain is done working, since the environment to that function isn't yet entirely based on RxJS. I'm aware of the `.toPromise` method, but I haven't used it yet. I might, though.

As to the cursor, it does emit the data over time in the same way as do NodeJS streams. It's one part that does work. See: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html

Comment: @nainy And what is this all supposed to do?

Comment: @martin Fetch documents from multiple cursors one after another into separate observables, then accumulate the documents inside those observables into one giant string, then count the word occurrences in those giant strings, then merge the results from every observable and output them to console (for now).

Comment: What dont you start with what you are trying to achieve. You just dump a bunch of code and ask about the right flow.